# How to recalculate offset from top of viewport to an element with height in vh after viewport change from portrait to landscape - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, addclass, scrolltop

I have a slideshow-wrapper which height equals 100vh, below I have a content-wrapper and I wanted a fixed menu-toggle to change its background when scrolled below the slideshow. I added on-slideshow class to the menu toggle on page load and used `.scrollTop()` to remove the class after scrolling below. The problem was I couldn't use vh in `.scrollTop()` so I also used `.offset().top` to calculate the distance from the top of viewport to content-wrapper. It all works fine until I change the view from portrait to landscape or resize the viewport. I am pretty sure I have to use `.addListener` for listening to the viewport state changes so the the distance could be recalculated, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".menu-toggle").addClass("on-slideshow");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
var distance = $(".content-wrapper").offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
         $(".menu-toggle").removeClass("on-slideshow");
    } else if ( $window.scrollTop() < distance ) {
         $(".menu-toggle").addClass("on-slideshow");
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Did you try just `$window.on('scroll resize orientationchange', function() {..` for your event handler, and getting the `distance` variable inside that event handler

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a million.